# how to perform simple collision detection between models in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am applying force to a rectangular model(created with spawn_model) that sends it colliding with another much denser model. What is the simplest way to access collision information? I was able to find the package collision_map for ros, but is there something else existing that I could use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1606/how-to-perform-simple-collision-detection-between-models-in-gazebo/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/239/mugetsu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can add a contact sensor to your model ([here's a tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.3/sensors/contact)), which will tell you the number of contact points, their location on the collision body, penetration depth, and reaction force/torque.

With Gazebo 1.4, you can also visualize contact in the gazebo client under the View menu, select Contacts. This will display each contact point as a blue sphere. You may also need to View->Transparent in case the contacts are blocked by visuals.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0